# How to make low level/plain SQL queries with SQLite-Net Extensions?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm using [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) and I want to check if a table exists, before I do some operations on it. This is what I tried:

```
await this.database.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{0}'", tableName).ContinueWith( t =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t.Result);
});
```

The output is `0`. If I query this directly on the database I get a result (`1`). Then I tried

```
var tableQuery = string.Format("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{0}'", tableName);
var result = await this.database.ExecuteAsync(tableQuery);
```

and I get an exception:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: Row
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x0009b] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2172 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:659 
  at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<ExecuteAsync>c__AnonStorey9.<>m__0 () [0x00013] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLiteAsync.cs:222 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at App.Database+<ClearTable>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00069] in xxx\Database.cs:1011 
  at App.Util.Helper+<CleanUpTemporaryFiles>d__8.MoveNext () [0x0013a] in xxx\Helper.cs:200 
  at App.Pages.DetailPage+<OnDisappearing>d__23.MoveNext () [0x000b1] in xxx\DetailPage.xaml.cs:449
```

For `QueryAsync` you need an object with a parameterless constructor.

Now I don't know how to make a simple `SELECT` query. Is there also a way to get a more detailed exception message than `Row`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are passing parameters into your SQL is incorrect. As per [the docs](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions), instead of

```
AND name='{0}'
```

you should use:

```
name = ?
```

Comment: Seems that you are right. I mixed this up with `string.Format()`. Is `ExecuteScalarAsync()` a suitable method for checking if a table exists? Are there other options than `ContinueWith`?

Comment: If it works, that sounds reasonable to me @testing .